# Is there a way to store a custom expression in Firebase Rules to be reused?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I would like to be able to reuse an expression in my Firebase Rules multiple times.

If I have the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
    "secretArea1": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'",
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'"
    },
    "secretArea2": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'",
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to store `root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role').val() === 'admin'` somewhere so it doesn't have to be repeated 4 times?

Something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false,
    "secretArea1": {
      ".read": "isAdmin",
      ".write": "isAdmin"
    },
    "secretArea2": {
      ".read": "isAdmin",
      ".write": "isAdmin"
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered [Blaze Compiler](https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler) which was linked at [Security & Rules Libraries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/libraries.html). Not exactly what I was looking for and adds an extra compile step but seems to provide the functionality I was looking for. It would be nice if it was included as an option in the Firebase Dashboard.

Comment: Also it seems a little buggy. Just a warning.

Comment: If you find bugs in Blaze, reporting them on the repo would be helpful. The current issue list shows 5 open bugs; not too buggy. If you're seeing otherwise, we want to know.

Comment: Sorry, I was frustrated with it last night. It works great when you get the syntax right. Sometimes it just seems really picky, could have better error messages, and some things I ran into weren't really documented. I added some issues: https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler/issues?q=author%3AOzzieOrca. Hopefully that helps :) I do like it better than writing the verbose json security rules.